# Is the Garden of Eden Goshen?

Tags: genesis

The Nile splits into 4 river heads. The etymology of the word Eden associates it with Isthmus. It is the only place that matches the description given in Genesis. Bolstering that the rare name association. Then in Genesis 13:10:

> And Lot lifted up his eyes, and beheld all the plain of Jordan, that it was well watered every where, before the Lord destroyed Sodom and Gomorrah,[[ even as the garden of the Lord, like the land of Egypt, as thou comest unto Zoar]].

All this together, is there any other way to interpret these facts, than this is the location of the Garden of Eden?

Answer (score 1):

### The etymology of the word Eden associates it with Isthmus.

Does it?

[H5731 - ʿēḏen - Strong's Hebrew Lexicon](https://www.blueletterbible.org/lexicon/h5731/kjv/wlc/0-1/) says that "עֵדֶן" has as its root [H5730 - ʿēḏen](https://www.blueletterbible.org/lexicon/h5730/kjv/wlc/0-1/), which means "luxury, dainty, or delight".

Without any supporting evidence, we can't assume that this claim is true.

#### it was well watered every where … even as the garden of the Lord, like the land of Egypt …

Other translations say "like the garden of the Lord, like the land of Egypt" or even "like the garden of the Lord and the land of Egypt", making it obvious that these are two distinct examples of well watered places, and not that Egypt and Eden are the same place.

#### is there any other way to interpret these facts, than this is the location of the Garden of Eden?

We have been given no reason to believe that the first *is* a fact, and the second appears to be the result of a misunderstanding of what the text says.

So yes, the facts *can* be interpreted to mean that just like Eden and Egypt, this land is well watered.

And we know that Egypt is well watered by the Nile, and that Eden is located at the source of the Euphrates (and three other rivers), which is nowhere near Egypt:

> Now **a river went out of Eden** to water the garden, and from there it parted **and became** four riverheads.
> … The fourth river is **the Euphrates**.
> — Genesis 2:10–14

Comment: Hey there, Ray. I appreciate the engagement with my question.

Comment: Hey there, Ray. I appreciate the engagement with my question. Here is a link to the etymology I was looking at  https://imgflip.com/i/7ku4tv.       The first alternate translation you gave leaves it very ambiguous as to whether it is referring to the same location or simply waxing poetic. The 2nd one with the and certainly implies a distinction, but that they are by no means mutually exclusive. I notice the river Euphrates and two other in the general vicinity are listed, but one river goes around the land of Cush, and Cush  is a region in more southerly Egypt.

Comment: There are no rivers that cross the Isthmus. One of these things is not like the other. My natural instinct would be that the odd one out is the real location.  https://imgflip.com/i/7ku53a

Answer (score 0):

**Garden of Eden?** Before we try to answer the specific question, notice the next verse: *This was before the Lord destroyed S and G.* (13:10 This sets up the mood for this answer.) Although many have tried to pinpoint the location of the Garden, no one has made a certain discovery. Some have located it in the mountains north of Persia; others have chosen the region around the Sinai peninsula as it touches the Euphrates. And now, the Egyptian delta.

What few searchers take into consideration is the fact that there has been a massive Noahic flood of biblical proportions!!! Any Garden that existed prior, was erased from the face of the Earth. It is therefore feckless to inquire as to the location of the Edenic Garden. The Garden *was before the Lord destroyed* the pre-noahic civilization and its geographical environment.

The Garden exists now only as a homiletic, symbolic reminder to resist the temptations of the Evil One. A reminder that man is a *fallen creature* in need of a Savior.

{That one of the names of the rivers of Eden, Euphrates, carries over into modern history does not rebut the force of this answer. As an aside, notice the number of times trees are mentioned in the same sentence as Eden, throughout the Bible references!}